# run screen after 'su'ing to a specific user

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, su

so, I have ssh setup on a Linux machine to start screen when user (root) logs in on ssh (on a basically single-user machine) I have dataplicity installed too, so I can access it from anywhere. when I remote to it, it runs as user dataplicity, so I su as root user to do anything, which doesn't reconnect to any available screen sessions. is there a way to add things that happens after 'su' only for a specific user?

Comment: It's not even so much that we don't understand the question, it's that we're wondering what the hell you're trying to accomplish, because chances are that the method you're asking for is the wrong way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `su -` to any user ID it means that you login to that ID . There is file on  user home directory which read after user logged in . In recent Linux it's `~/.profile` or in older version `~/.bash_profile` . You can add anything which start when user logged in in this file . If you couldn't find these files on user home directory try to edit `~/.bashrc` .

Comment: But this will be executed for all root logins. As I understand the question, the `screen` session should only be reattached if user dataplicity `su`s into root account.

Comment: He can put `screen -r` in any user `.profile` so whenever user login screen will attached again .

Comment: Either you don't understand what I'm trying to say or the other way around, so I better keep out of it.

Answer (score 0):

`su` stands for "switch user" and logs you in as the user you indicate.  If you don't indicate a user, then you log in as root.

The `-` invokes a new login shell, which cleans your slate of environment variables.

If it is safe to do so, you can use `sudo` to run a command as a privileged user, while remaining logged in as dataplicity.  For example:

`sudo lastb`

The machine will ask you for the dataplicity login and then run `lastb` (checks for failed logins) as a privileged user.

In order to use `sudo` from your dataplicity account, you would need to add dataplicity to your `/etc/sudoers` account (in SUSE).  Do this by using:

`su -`

`visudo`

Then add: `dataplicity ALL=(ALL) ALL` to the list.  Usually you add it right after the `root ALL=(ALL) ALL` entry.

Comment: While all of this is true and well explained, it doesn't seem to address the question: How to attach to a running `screen` session automatically only when `su`ing from a specific user?

Comment: I am suggesting to use `sudo` on commands instead of logging into root with `su -`.  That way, commands such as `screen` should be run from and apply to the dataplicity account instead of to the root account.  It should also not wipe out the environmental variables opened by dataplicity.

But that's assuming the specific user that pcs3rd wants `sudo` actions applied to is the dataplicity account.

Comment: I don't believe he wants that, but he seems to have lost interest in the answer, so I vote to close the question.

Comment: ... im using Kali

Comment: Kali and SUSE are both Debian based, so the above command should work.  If that's what you're looking for.